# Get two target possibilities by random forest or svm

Tags: machine-learning, svm, random-forest

I have a dataset with sequence tuples and targets like the following:

```
       input_0  input_1 input_2 output
0        0       1.0    2.0      4.0
1        1       2.0    4.0      2.0
2        2       4.0    2.0      4.0
3        4       2.0    4.0      7.0
4        2       4.0    7.0      8.0
```

I have trained algorithms using the output as a target value.

What I want though, is to get the two most possible variables that can occur by one tupple.

For example if i have two tuples for training: `a,b,c,d` and `a,b,c,e` I want to get `d` and `e` as a result with the respective percentage.

Is there something like that possible?